# Dovecot Migration and old mails

Tags: imap, migration, postfix, dovecot

I'm migrating my mails from an old server to a new one, the configuration is good (mysql virtual accounts & **imap only**), with dovecot and postfix.
It's already running for other users, I just want to merge old accounts from the old server to the new one.

The migration went fine, I just wanted to know how I could "**show**" all the old mails in UA Clients. I mean, is there any **dovecot index** file or such that could be re-created, destroyed, so that all old mails are "flagged" as **new** ?

Comment: Are you using mbox or maildir format for the email store?

Comment: Actually `maildir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maildir actually uses a unique format that makes this quite easy. Simply place the mail in `new/` directory inside the mail users mailroot if you want it to show up as new. Otherwise it goes in the `cur/` directory.

Comment: Is the ,S flag appended to the file name that makes the Seen status for IMAP and POP3. cur and new folders are kept only for efficiency matters

Comment: I suppose it depends on the MUA implementation but as I understand it (admittedly not having read the source for Dovecot) is that flags such as `S` are not read when emails are in `new/` and are instead added when the MUA moves the file from `new/` to `cur/`. I've not come across anything that considers these two directories as vestigial; every Maildir implementation I've run into uses them. See: http://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html

Comment: while all these comments re:filenames+folder-structure are pretty valid, they're not universally true - from one dovecot to the next it went from ".Sent" to "Sent" (no dot) for our setups. **dovecot import** and **dovecot sync** should be more robust solutions. See my answer @ https://serverfault.com/a/866298/300859

Answer (score 8):

I tried the accepted answer and it failed - the dovecot versions in play are probably too far apart and we also switched the underlying MTA. So here is a more robust solution: **doveadm import**

Assuming you're hosting emails for the domain **hosted.tld** and an account exists for the login **local.account@hosted.tld** (or maybe simply **ruth**) and the backup from the previous server is in MailDir format and available inside a folder structure like **/tmp/TRANSFER/*domain*/*account*/Maildir** then you can import them to your new dovecot hosting with

```
$ doveadm import -u local.account@hosted.tld maildir:/tmp/TRANSFER/hosted.tld/local.account/Maildir "" all
```

more generally speaking:

```
$ doveadm import -u LOCAL_USER FORMAT:PATH "" all
```

All of which can be gleened from the [*fine manual*](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Import). It took two tries to find out simply using "" (empty destination mailbox) was what we *really* wanted ;-)

You may even have more luck than us without needing to transfer the files beforehand - if old and new server are running at the same time and your accounts are set up appropriately using [**doveadm sync**](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Sync).

Comment: I know this is a while ago but.. do you know how to specify a root level destination folder other than "INBOX" (i.e. "")? If I try "Test" it automatically gets appended with ".INBOX". So the destination folder is ".Test.INBOX" and in the UI (Roundcube) I get a folder hierarchy: Test -> INBOX. I was just hoping for Test!!

Comment: For anyone else, since the mails were already in Maildir format, I ended up just moving the folder to ".Test" in the users mailbox and 'chown -R mail:mail' ing the destination

Answer (score 5):

For Maildir messages, such flags are stored in the *file name*. For example:

```
1328040798.M558634P29803.equal,S=17876,W=18294:2,FS
```

The letters `FS` after the comma mean `Flagged` and `Seen`. To mark the message as "unseen", either remove the `S` flag...

```
for msg in maildir/cur/*; do
    msgbase=${msg%,*}
    flags=${msg##*,}
    flags=${flags//S/}
    mv -v "$msg" "$msgbase,$flags"
done
```

...or simply throw the messages into the `new` folder:

```
mv maildir/cur/* maildir/new/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but Garret & Paul answered right before you ! ;)

Comment: Deserves a +1 just because of the nifty BaSH-ery! :)

Answer (score 4):

The Maildir format consists of a series of directories - matching the IMAP folder structure, within which are the emails, one file per email.

In order to copy emails from one email system to another, you can simply copy the directories and files, and ensure the permissions for those directories and files are correct at the destination.

The Maildir structure looks like this:

```
mail/cur/
mail/new/
mail/tmp/
mail/.personal/cur/
mail/.personal/new/
mail/.personal/tmp/
```

This shows the INBOX folder (cur, new, tmp) and another folder called "personal".  Note the dot prefix showing that this folder is hidden, so this should be accounted for in your transfer.

The `new` folder contains any emails that have not been seen by a client, and the `cur` folder contains current emails.  The `tmp` folder should be empty if the mail server is not operating.

Comment: @grawity - just so you are aware, the actual name of the mail directory varies across distributions - I used the placeholder "Maildir" to signify the maildir folder, not necessarily that it is called that (I should have noted this of course, and incidentally, on some of my mail servers it actually is Maildir)

Comment: @Paul: Many configurations *do* call it "Maildir", which often causes confusion -- people think that Maildir-format mailboxes are always located in ~/Maildir, or they don't know when someone is talking about the path versus the format... that's the reason why I changed your example. (On the second thought, I probably shouldn't have.)

Comment: @grawity No, hang on, you are right - I generally have mailboxes in `~` but this is definitely not always the case and I didn't consider that.  The edit makes sense.

Comment: After playing with files remember to delete dovecot-uidlist and courierimapuiddb files otherwise mail clients won't see changes inmediately

Comment: Just make sure file permissions / owner:group match